# Convert PNG to JPG - Need link to storage but it wont work

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code to upload an avatar:

```
    if(request()->file("avatar_upload")) {
       $file = request()->file("avatar_upload");
        $ext = $file->guessClientExtension();
        if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg"){
        $file->storeAs('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id , "avatar.jpg");
        }
        if($ext == "png"){
            $file->storeAs('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id , "avatar.png");
            $imageobject = imagecreatefrompng('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id . "/avatar.png");
            imagejpeg($imageobject, "avatar.jpg");
        }
    }
```

The function `imagecreatefrompng` however can never find the uploaded avatar (I use sylinks)

I tried this:

```
$imageobject = imagecreatefrompng('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id . "/avatar.png")
```

which gives me this error:

```
imagecreatefrompng(public/avatars/1/avatar.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

and also tried this:

```
 $imageobject = imagecreatefrompng('storage/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id . "/avatar.png");
```

Which doesnt give me any error but does nothing at all

Comment: You need the absolute path for imagecreatefrom*

Comment: @KyleDomingo Though so. But I am also sure that there is some way in laravel to create such path so I have no problem when migrating my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this. Use laravel core function to get path of public folder. Also make sure the directory where you want to save the file must have permissions set to 0777.

```
if(request()->file("avatar_upload")) {
       $file = request()->file("avatar_upload");
        $ext = $file->guessClientExtension();
        if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg"){
        $file->storeAs('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id , "avatar.jpg");
        }
        if($ext == "png"){
          $imageName = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $file->move(public_path().'/avatars/'.Auth::user()->id,$imageName);

            $imageobject = imagecreatefrompng(public_path().'/avatars/'.Auth::user()->id. '/avatar.png');
            //-----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^----here
            imagejpeg($imageobject, 'avatar.jpg',100);
            remove old image
            imagedestroy($imageobject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: imagecreatefrompng(C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\public/avatars/1/avatar.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. I have also tried making the / \ and it still wont work.

Comment: @prgrm if still not working let me know i have another solution for this.

Comment: There is no chance it works. If you dont use the storeAs function the image wont even be there.

Comment: @prgrm $file->move will move your file and rename itself. Did you try ?

Comment: @prgrm you forgot to add Auth::user()->id while moveing the image :).
test now!!

Comment: You guys ever heard of [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)?

Answer (score 1):

according to your comments if it is sym-linked then it should be like this

```
$imageobject = imagecreatefrompng(storage_path('app/public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id . "/avatar.png"));
imagejpeg($imageobject, "avatar.jpg");
```

Comment: Nope, the image is uploaded but not converted

Comment: @prgrm did you try my solutions?

Comment: yes I get this error: imagecreatefrompng(C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\public\avatars\1\avatar.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. The true directory is:C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\storage\app\public\avatars\1. There is a .symlink called "storage" in myproject/public that points directly to /myproject/storage/public

Comment: @prgrm  try it now

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(request()->file("avatar_upload")) {
          $file = request()->file("avatar_upload");
          $ext = $file->guessClientExtension();
        if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "png"){
         $file->storeAs('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id , "avatar.jpg");
        }
    }
```

There is no need to separate the png and jpeg. You can simply storeAs avatar.jpg the image itself too.